# Настройка 3proxy по доменам и сетям

Tags: linux, сервер, proxy, socks5

У tinyproxy есть такая настройка, как `upstram socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 ".onion"`, которая означает "перенаправлять все запросы с доменом onion в Тор-сокс. Однако в силу ограничей tinyproxy (только HTTP и отсутствие настройки IPv6) предпринята попытка перехода на `3proxy`.

Как здесь можно настроить тонкую маршрутизацию клиента по подсетям (интерфейсам) в зависимости от целевого адреса? Есть такой вариант `parent 1000 socks5+ 127.0.0.1 9050`, перенаправляющий весь трафик через Tor, но это слишком топорная настройка. Например, нельзя при надобности избирательно отправлять пользователя в локальный i2p-прокси или в Yggdrasil при IPv6 запросе из подсети 200::/7.

В документации работы с доменами вообще не нашел толковой, но, возможно, чего-то просто не понял.

Comment: Все ваши проблемы от того что лень изучить [iptables](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/). Отсюда и плодятся всякие tinyproxy, 3proxy и прочие всевозможные программные маршрутизаторы, которые по сути умеют две с половиной опции, при этом не умеют остальные 15 опций. Зато такой богатый выбор... глаза разбегаются!

Comment: @DiD на лени строится прогресс! :)